# org.gradle.tooling.model.UnsupportedMethodException: Unsupported method: AndroidArtifact.getBuildConfigFields()

Tags: android-studio

I was building my android project on Android Studio 4.2.1.
but I get this error:

```
org.gradle.tooling.model.UnsupportedMethodException: Unsupported method: 
    AndroidArtifact.getBuildConfigFields().
    The version of Gradle you connect to does not support that method.
    To resolve the problem you can change/upgrade the target version of Gradle you connect to.
    Alternatively, you can ignore this exception and read other information from the model.
```

my Gradle version:

```
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-6.4.1-bin.zip
```

my Gradle plugin tools version:

```
com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.1.0-alpha09
```

The both Gradle and Gradle plugin are the latest versions. The exception says that I need to update/change the connected Gradle version.

I am impossible to upgrade further version because I am already on the latest version. So, the only thing I can do is changing the grade version, but which one?

Comment: It looks like a bug in either Gradle and/or the Android Gradle Plugin. There is a bug open in the Google issue tracker: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/155936233. It looks like upgrading to Android Studio Canary 9 fixes it.

Comment: Downgrade its version to 4.0.1

Answer (score 1):

I was able to build project successfully by using :

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.0.0'
```

But if you are trying to use jetpack compose you will have to use latest canary version of android studio.